# CONVERT(varchar, COLNAME, 120) doesn't work in sqlite java

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

So I'm trying to query all the same dates but this code won't work

```
SELECT  * FROM schedTBL WHERE CONVERT(varchar, DueDateTime, 120) LIKE  " + "'%"+ text + "%'"
```

it returns no such column:varchar

Comment: Can you try this convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 120)?

Comment: what is @now used for?

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, date values would be formatted with the [strftime() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), or for this particular format, with the date() function:

```
... WHERE date(DueDateTime) LIKE ...
```

But this works only for [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).
If the values in your database use an unsupported format, your only choice is to convert them, or to try to match the actual string:

```
... WHERE DueDateTime LIKE ...
```

Comment: Then you're using a wrong [date format](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5252/data-types/18688/date-time-types).

Comment: my datetime format is like this 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a'

Comment: That is not ISO8601.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a SQL statement for SQL Server, not SQLite...

Assuming you are storing dates in field `DueDateTime` without the hour part, something like this should do:

`SELECT  * FROM schedTBL WHERE DueDateTime = '2016-09-24'`

Or you'll need `like` if you also have hour values. That depends on how you are actually storing dates/times in your SQLite DB.

Try formatting the date in Java and send it as a parameter to your query.
SQLite doesn't handle dates like SQL Server.
See:
[SQLite Date And Time Functions](http://sqlite.org/lang%5Fdatefunc.html)